# NFC: What is the difference between S-beam and Android beam?

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

NFC: What is the difference between S-beam and Android beam? Can someone explain the exact flow of Wifi-Direct/Bluetooth getting activated and transferring the data?

Comment: Refer to this

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26509/whats-the-difference-between-android-beam-vs-s-beam

It's perfectly explained there :)

Comment: Thanks Max for the link, I did go through that ( and I was a bit aware of that), as the link speaks of the WifiDirect/Bluetooth, (and the Speed, wifi is faster than BT, furthermore to add in S-Beam can transfer bigger size data ),  just want to know something more on that, can you please share more info. Any idea where I can get the code flow kind off... Thanks in advance

Comment: Found something more, the S-Beam initialisation takes more time compared to Android beam. (But that guy didn't disclose the algo :( or any other useful info). Will keep exploring and updating

Answer (score 6):

Explained on stackexchanged....

> Even though Android Beam and S Beam serve similar purposes, they
>   actually work very differently and are not compatible with one
>   another.
>
> Android Beam uses NFC to pair your devices over Bluetooth, then
>   transfers files over the Bluetooth connection. I believe it can also
>   transfer very small pieces of data (contacts, links, etc) directly
>   over NFC, as the Ice Cream Sandwich version highlights page implies:
>
> For larger payloads, developers can even use Android Beam to initiate
>   a connection and transfer the data over Bluetooth, without the need
>   for user-visible pairing. S Beam, however, uses Wi-Fi Direct to
>   perform data transfers instead of Bluetooth. Their reasoning for doing
>   this is that Wi-Fi Direct offers faster transfer speeds (they quote up
>   to 300 Mbps). Therefore, this will only work with other S Beam enabled
>   devices, currently limiting it to communication between two Galaxy
>   S3s.
>
> However, the SGS3 also supports Android Beam, so you can use that to
>   transfer something between a GNex and an SGS3. Here is a tutorial on
>   Sprint's website (should be essentially the same for other versions of
>   the SGS3).